# how can we increase size of zoomed image in magento demo

Tags: magento-1.9, zooming

I am using magento 1.9 . i want to increase the size of image zooming . That means while hover over on product image it will show a zoom frame, i wanted the zoom size should be larger then by default. can anyone help me out on this situation.